# sensor_msgs::CvBridge::cvToImgMsg in Groovy?

Tags: ros, cv-bridge, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

Following the tutorial in Ros Wiki for creating a simple image publisher (from a set of .png files) http://ros.org/wiki/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages I found a compilation error in groovy (in fuerte everything works fine):

```
cv::WImageBuffer3_b image(cvLoadImage(filePath.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR));
sensor_msgs::ImagePtr msg = sensor_msgs::CvBridge::cvToImgMsg(image.Ipl(), "bgr8");
```

This is the error I found:

```
 error: ‘sensor_msgs::CvBridge’ has not been declared
```

I suppose that the API has changed, but I cannot find an alternative way. Can somebody help me?

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60279/sensor_msgs::cvbridge::cvtoimgmsg-in-groovy?/) by [Javier J. Salmerón García](https://answers.ros.org/users/4037/javier-j.-salmer%C3%B3n-garc%C3%ADa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to sort it out the following way, using this answer as a reference http://answers.ros.org/question/9765/how-to-convert-cvmat-to-sensor_msgsimageptr/?answer=14282#post-id-14282 :

```
cv::WImageBuffer3_b image(
                    cvLoadImage(filePath.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR));
            cv::Mat imageMat(image.Ipl());


            cv_bridge::CvImage out_msg;
            out_msg.encoding = sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8; 
            out_msg.image    = imageMat;
            out_msg.header.seq = i;
            out_msg.header.frame_id = i;
            out_msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

            ci->header.seq = i;
            ci->header.frame_id = i;
            ci->header.stamp = out_msg.header.stamp;

            pub.publish(out_msg.toImageMsg(), ci);
```

---

Originally posted by [Javier J. Salmerón García](https://answers.ros.org/users/4037/javier-j.-salmer%C3%B3n-garc%C3%ADa/) with karma: 114 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on 2013-09-07**:
What does i refer to? I am trying to convert Mat to sensor_msgs::image need help with header values.